# Separation between regular web site requests and API requests

Tags: api, api-design, web-services

I have a doubt about the architecture of a web app when it comes down to differentiating between regular website requests and API requests.

For the purpose of explaining, suppose I am the creator of a service (let's take [darksky.net](https://darksky.net) for example). I offer both a website and APIs.

On one side I have my API endpoints, for instance `GET https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[key]/[latitude],[longitude]` that allow a developer to extract weather forecast for a specific `[latititude/longitude]` pair. I want people to pay to use those APIs. In order to do so, they have to sign up to the website and pay a subscription in order to to be granted a token (`[key]`) that allows them to authenticate to the APIs and so perform requests (how we use the token to authenticate the requests does not matter).

On the other side I also have a website that I want people to have access to to look up weather forecasts. There is a search form where you can type in a location and the website shows you the forecast for that location. If I want to know the forecats for San Francisco, I type San Francisco and search.
In a modern website, this means that there is some Javascript code associated with the location form that performs a request to the server to get the information. Most likely, the location name is also translated into a `[latitude, longitude]` pair and the request is done by the coordinates instead of the location name.

Now, here comes my doubt. I would expect the website to use the APIs, since the API does exactly what the website wants, which is to return weather forecast information of a specific location. The website JS code would then interpret the API response and use it to graphically display information on the website.
But this would not be a nice solution. Doing this would mean that we would have to have a token stored somewhere on the client side code to authenticate requests. This would allow anyone that is able to do `F12` on a webpage and go through the code to access it and basically get a free API token to use, instead of paying a subscription to the API service.

So, how do you differentiate the two situations?

Please let me know if my question was not clear.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Have the website use the api, but from the server side.

```
client -> website (secret token on server) -> api -> website -> client
```